# How to check if an object value is equal to a string in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, append

I'm making a music writing website, and I'm wondering how I can check if an object and a string in an array are equal. The outcome I want is qnoteC to append to b1b1. Here's my code. The line at the bottom is what I need solved.

```
const notesarray = ['C','Db','D']
const input = document.getElementById('chordsinput')
const b1b1 = document.querySelector('.b1b1')
const b1b2 = document.querySelector('.b1b2')
const b1b3 = document.querySelector('.b1b3')
const b1b4 = document.querySelector('.b1b4')
const qnoteC = document.createElement('img')
const qnoteDb = document.createElement('img')
const qnoteD = document.createElement('img')

//C
qnoteC.src = 'quarternote.png'
qnoteC.style.width = '32px'
qnoteC.style.position = 'relative'
qnoteC.style.bottom = '8px'
//Db
qnoteDb.src = 'quarternoteflat.png'
qnoteDb.style.width = '32px'
qnoteDb.style.position = 'relative'
qnoteDb.style.bottom = '61px'
//D
qnoteD.src = 'quarternote.png'
qnoteD.style.width = '32px'
qnoteD.style.position = 'relative'
qnoteD.style.bottom = '110px'


generate.addEventListener('click', generateclick)


function generateclick(){
index = notesarray.indexOf(chordsinput.value)
if(index >= 0 )
fifth = notesarray[index + 7]
if(fifth == undefined){
fifth = notesarray[index - 5]}

if(fifth == notesarray[0]){
b1b1.appendChild(qnoteC)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question, but I believe you can just check if `array[0] == string` just fine. If you need to check an object against an object or an array against an array, simply iterate through that object/array and check if the current element is equal to the current element in the *other* object/array.